# Getting error in css while using it with php?

Tags: css, button, hover

hi i am new to css and php too i tried to use it in my php site i have css as follow in which i am trying to change image on hover but i am getting error and my half images changing only ...

[image]

while the images i am using are,

[image]

[image]

my css code is,

```
#header #nav a {
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px; 
    padding-left:17px; 
    background:url("../design/nav-l.png") 0 -35px no-repeat; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#header #nav a span {
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
    padding-right:17px; 
    background:url("../design/nav-r.png") 100% -35px no-repeat; 
    line-height:35px;
}
#header #nav a:hover { background-position:0 -100px; }
#header #nav a:hover span { background-position:100% -70px; }
```

hopes for your reply thanks in advance !

Best Regards,

Comment: use firebug, great tool.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP.  You'll have a lot better luck if you post a url which illustrates the problem.  Ditto on firebug and web developer plugins.

Comment: You should not tag this question with "PHP"

Comment: is there any error in this css??

Comment: The whole problem is with while you hover at that the image positioning is not being set properly

Comment: @rajan what would be the position i am not getting it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix % and px on the same CSS value.

```
background:url("../design/nav-r.png") 100% -35px no-repeat;
#header #nav a:hover span { background-position:100% -70px; }
```

These two lines are invalid CSS and are probably causing the parser to freak out. Start by setting them using either % *or* px, but not a combination of both.

```
background-position: 100px -35px; <--- OK  
background-position: 100% 50% <--- OK  
background-position: 100% 100px <--- Invalid
```

If the UI is not behaving correctly after that, you should use a web inspector like Firebug or the inspector built into your browser to see what's going on under the hood. This will often give you big clues as to what is wrong with your styles.

If you're still stuck after trying to fix the problem yourself using a web inspector, update the question with more detail (what have you tried, what was the result) and we'll have a better shot at helping you fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code below nav-r is your small image where nav-bg is your big bg image

```
#header #nav a {
    color: #fff;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px; 
    padding-left:17px; 
    background:url("nav-r.png") 0 -35px no-repeat; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#header #nav a span {
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
    padding-right:17px; 
    background:url("nav-bg.png") 100% -35px no-repeat; 
    line-height:35px;
}
#header #nav a:hover { background-position:0 -70px; }
#header #nav a:hover span { background-position:100% -70px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
    <div id='nav'>
        <a href='#'><span>Rajan Rawal</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you check this out properly then you just change the below css and see magic

```
#header #nav a {
    color: #fff;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7px; 
    padding-left:17px; 
    background:url("nav-r.png") 0 0 no-repeat; 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#header #nav a span {
    float:left; 
    display:block; 
    padding-right:17px; 
    background:url("nav-bg.png") 100% 0 no-repeat; 
    line-height:35px;
}
```